# 2 iOS app with different with bundle identifier in 1 onesignal app

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

We are working on the On-demand Photography app.
So basically we have.
2 android apps (user and photographer)
2 iOS apps (user and photographer)

android push configured with firebase and firebase allows us to configure 2 android apps against one firebase key. So multiple android apps are working on 1 one signal app id.

but iOS side doest not allow us to do so, we need to configure 2 iOS apps with 1 one signal app id.

How we can make this possible?

Comment: Hi Aali, I have same issues, Did you get the solution ?

Comment: Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not use two OneSignal apps in a single iOS app. Instead, you can use OneSignal's [data tags](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/add-user-data-tags) feature to create segments of users based on whether they are a user or a photographer, and to send them different notifications based on this.

Comment: Your answer is wrong, he is asking how to use single one signal app to two different iOS apps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible. You would need to create an OneSignal app for each of these two apps. A single OneSignal App can include 1 of each platform (Website, Android App, iOS App, Email, etc.).

Refer this, https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/dashboard